# Nudity and Lack of Shame in Gen 2:25

Tags: genesis

> Gen 2:25 - And the man and his wife were both naked, and they were not
> ashamed.

Can I ask you to point me to a book or article where I can find a summary of the most important views on the issue of nudity and lack of shame (before sinning in the Garden of Eden)?

(I do not mean a source that discusses one interpretation, but one that juxtaposes many interpretations.)

Comment: You could start with https://biblehub.com/commentaries/genesis/2-25.htm  and https://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/ and  https://www.biblegateway.com/resources/commentaries/  and  https://www.blueletterbible.org/commentaries/

Comment: I know these things. I mean a scientific article or book that describes a spectrum of views on Gen 2:25 (and Gen 3:7)

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.